# Concentration Inequality for cross-entropy

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, cross-entropy

I am currently trying to estimate the cross-entropy between two distributions with densities $p$ and $q$.

$$
\ell = -\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x) }[\log q(x)]
$$

I am using a Monte-Carlo estimate:
$$
\hat{\ell} = -\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\log p(x_{i})
$$

**Is there a standard way to devise a concentration inequality for this estimate?** That is, a probabilistic bound of the form

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\big|\hat{\ell} - \ell\big| > \varepsilon \right) \leq f(n, \varepsilon)
$$

that holds with some probability $1-\delta(n, \varepsilon)$ where $f$ is some function of $\epsilon$ and the number of samples $n$? I thought about using Hoeffding's inequality but there is no upper bound on the density $q$. Ideally, if even possible, I would like a bound that makes no/weak assumptions on the density $q$.

Even in the case when $q$ is discrete and $0 \leq q(x) \leq 1$, I am worried that the logarithm will cause issues in devising a useful bound.

Comment: I might be missing something, but without any assumptions, i.e., bounded variance, I don't see how such a bound could exist. If you do assume that such a bound exists, I imagine you could then leverage Hoeffding/Bernstein's inequality for a probabilistic bound of the form $f(n,\varepsilon, \delta)$, which holds with some probability $1 - \delta$.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should have included that I want this to be a probabilistic bound, I will edit the question to reflect this.